# Given a sorted dictionary of an alien language, find order of characters

Tags: python, algorithm

> Given a sorted dictionary (array of words) of an alien language, find
>   order of characters in the language.

[Link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-sorted-dictionary-find-precedence-characters/):
The idea is to create a graph of characters and then find topological sorting of the created graph. Following are the detailed steps.

1) Create a graph g with number of vertices equal to the size of alphabet in the given alien language. For example, if the alphabet size is 5, then there can be 5 characters in words. Initially there are no edges in graph.

2) Do following for every pair of adjacent words in given sorted array.

```
a) Let the current pair of words be word1 and word2. One by one compare 
   characters of both words and find the first mismatching characters.

b) Create an edge in g from mismatching character of word1 to that of 
   word2.
```

3) Print topological sorting of the above created graph.

```
import collections


def topological_sort(nodes_map, nodes):
    def recursion(nodes_map, node, result, visited):
        if node in visited:
            return
        visited.append(node)
        if node in nodes_map:
            for c in nodes_map[node]:
                recursion(nodes_map, c, result, visited)
        result.append(node)

    visited, result = [], []
    for node in nodes.keys()[::-1]:
        recursion(nodes_map, node, result, visited)
    return reversed(result)


words = ["baa", "abcd", "abca", "cab", "cad"]
chars = collections.OrderedDict()
for word in words:
    for c in word:
        chars[c] = True

nodes_map = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i, word in enumerate(words[:-1]):
    nxt = words[i+1]
    for a, b in zip(word, nxt):
        if a != b:
            nodes_map[a] += [b]
            break
for i in topological_sort(nodes_map, chars):
    print i,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
words = ["baa", "abcd", "abca", "cab", "cad"]
```

I don't believe you ever mutate `words` so you should make it constant by making it a tuple:

```
words = ("baa", "abcd", "abca", "cab", "cad")
```

This:

```
words = ["baa", "abcd", "abca", "cab", "cad"]
chars = collections.OrderedDict()
for word in words:
    for c in word:
        chars[c] = True

    nodes_map = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for i, word in enumerate(words[:-1]):
        nxt = words[i+1]
        for a, b in zip(word, nxt):
            if a != b:
                nodes_map[a] += [b]
                break
    for i in topological_sort(nodes_map, chars):
        print i,
```

Should probably wrapped into a ["main function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do). Furthermore, to keep stuff in the "main scope" I highly recomend you actually make a `main` function. So instead of just:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    words = ("baa", "abcd", "abca", "cab", "cad")
    chars = collections.OrderedDict()
    ...
```

You should do:

```
def main():
    words = ("baa", "abcd", "abca", "cab", "cad")
    nodes_map = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for i, word in enumerate(words[:-1]):
        nxt = words[i+1]
        for a, b in zip(word, nxt):
            if a != b:
                nodes_map[a] += [b]
                break
    for i in topological_sort(nodes_map, chars):
         print i,

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Instead of using a list to store `results` change it to a dequeue by making it `results = collection.dequeue()`. This gives you the `appendleft` method which adds stuff to the beginning of the "list". This means you don't need to `return reversed(results)`, just return `results`.

Answer (score 2):

I would make `visited` a `set`, so that `if node in visited` becomes \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$, instead of \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$. You will also have to replace `visited.append(node)` with `visited.add(node)`.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you used `\$\mathcal\$` instead of `\$O\$`?

Comment: @Coal_ Because I like it more